# When pairing armature to object the obect "jumps" away

Tags: rigging, objects, armature, bones

I made an armature/bones in rigify and tried to pair it to the object and the object jumps away when pairing and is not in the object. What do i wrong? I guess it has to do with the black line at the bottom but i cannot figure out how to solve it (absolute beginner)

[image]

Comment: It looks as if the origins (orange dot) of the armature and character are in different places. Could you please share your Blend file? Copy the browser's URL to this question then go to https://blend-exchange.com/. Paste the link into the field to the left of the 'Upload' button and drag and drop the Blend file as instructed.

Comment: Select the model and clear its parent (*Alt+P*), then select the armature and press *Ctrl+A > Location* in *Object* mode to apply the location. Do the same for the model. Then try again. This moves the origin (orange dot) to (0,0,0) and ensures that both objects are at the same spot.